# Is it possible to map the shift + right click "copy as path" function to a keyboard only shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I use shift + right click, copy as path all the time.  It would be very handy to be mapped to Ctrl + Shift + C or Ctrl + Alt + C.  The best I've come up with thus-far is Shift + Menu, A.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcut key of right-click. The button marked in the picture below and Shift+F10 are the shortcut keys for right-clicking the mouse.

[image]

You can use " Shift+F10+A " or " Shift+the button marked in the picture+A " to achieve your purpose. First you press "Shift+F10" or "Shift+the button marked in the picture", then press "A" after showing the picture below.

[image]

Strictly speaking, this may not be a shortcut on the keyboard. You can also use some third-party tools to implement your needs, such as [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: that's the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)

Comment: @phuclv Thank you for your correction, I modified my description.

Answer (score 0):

As S.Leon stated in his answer, this can be accomplished with AutoHotkey. Below is a script that maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copying a file to a path.

```
^!c::
  Clipboard = ; Empty the Clipboard
  SendInput ^c
  ClipWait, 3 ; Wait up to three seconds for the clipboard to contain text
  if ErrorLevel
  {
    MsgBox, The attempt to copy the path to the clipboard failed.
    Return
  }
  Clipboard = %Clipboard% ; Convert file to path
Return
```

This same script can be used to copy formatted text as plain text.